# How to avoid running Virtual Makefile targets more than once?

Tags: makefile

I want to depend on a virtual target that only runs once.

`Makefile` with what I tried so far:

```
a: b

b: c d
    touch b

c:
    # time consuming task that only needs to run once

d:
    # time consuming task that only needs to run once
```

Is there a way to stop the dependency chain when `b` already exists? I'm okay with making a manual clean to get rid of `b` to trigger a re-run of `c` and `d`. I want to be able to run `a` many times without triggering the long running tasks if `b` exists.

I have a lot of tasks like `c` and `d`, so I want to avoid touching a file per separate task and I don't want the file system to be cluttered with unnecessary files.

Comment: You say you want the running of `c` to depend on whether `b` exists. You also say "I have a lot of tasks like `c`, so I want to avoid touching a file per separate task and I don't want the file system to be cluttered with unnecessary files." This looks like a contradiction.

Comment: `c` is a task that produces input files on disk, but I can't rely on those files to be the same, so there are no physical files to depend on. `b` just has `c` as a prerequisite.

Comment: If the set of files produced by `c` is unpredictable, how does `b` find them in order to make use of them? Maybe the same method can be implemented in the makefile to write accurate prerequisites for b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your Makefile as:

```
a: b

b c:
    # time consuming task that only needs to run once
    touch b
```

`make c` will call your task unconditionally.

`make b` only executes your task when the file b does not exist.

`make a` depends on b, so the task is only executed when b does not exist,

Comment: Runing, for example, `a` five times, I only want `b` to be run once.

Comment: I think you should clarify the question. Calling "make a" five times will result in your "time consuming task" being run only once in the script above.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I want!